AWS Comprehend Analysis job s3 output file gives "authorized to perform: kms:Decrypt"
We are currently running the Comprehend Analysis job in a separate AWS account (let's call it Account A1), and the output is stored in an S3 bucket in another account (Account A2). After the job completes, we attempt to download the output file from the S3 bucket in Account A2.
However, we're encountering a permissions issue, with the following error:

software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: User: user is not authorized to perform: kms:Decrypt on the resource associated with this ciphertext because the resource does not exist in this Region, no resource-based policies allow access, or a resource-based policy explicitly denies access (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID:id

It’s important to note that we did not specify encryption or a KMS key during the creation of the analysis job.

It sounds like the S3 bucket in A2 that Comprehend writes to has a default encryption with KMS configured (SSE-KMS) and because of that the data gets encrypted using that key.
If you want to read that data, you need permission to call the decrypt operation on that key. For details about setting that up, check the official docs: Allowing users in other accounts to use a KMS key.
